# Grab a FK's string value from different Table during Select with linq in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table `Users` and a table `PastElo`. I am trying to make a new variable (`s1rank`) to store a `User` value which is referenced in PastElo during a `select` statement.

i.e. (tables are condensed down)

`---User---
id: int (PK)
name: string
elo: int (FK -> id in PastElo)`

`---PastElo---
id: int (PK)
rank: string`

`rank` is the name of the User's `elo`, and I am trying to keep track of `elo`'s string name or at least be able to access it, after returning a `List` of all Users.

```
    var result = db.Users.Select(x => new { x.name, x.email, x.summoner, 
                 x.birthday,x.school, x.bio, x.champ1, x.champ2, x.champ3, 
                 x.elo, x.facebook, x.rank,x.role1, x.role2, x.s1elo, x.s2elo,
                 x.s3elo, x.s4elo, x.steam, x.stream, x.summonerID, 

                 //my attempt to get rank's value for elo's int
                 s1rank = x.PastElo.Rank.Select(x.s1elo == x.PastElo.ID) }

                 ).ToList();
```

After that occurs it is then passed off to an AngularJS service. Is there a simple way to get that User's string/name of their `elo` value?

So when I say `{{users.s1rank}}` I want that to hold the string name for a User's elo rank, not the `int`value of elo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for an answer, what I did was the following in order to get the FK `int`s from several other tables which contained their `string` value/name.

```
            var query = from users in db.Users
                        join s1 in db.PastEloes on users.s1elo equals s1.ID
                        join s2 in db.PastEloes on users.s2elo equals s2.ID
                        join e in db.eloLists on users.elo equals e.ID
                        join r in db.rankLists on users.rank equals r.ID
                        select new
                        {
                            elo1 = s1.Rank,
                            elo2 = s2.Rank,
                            elo = e.rank,
                            rank = r.rank,
                            sortElo = users.elo,
                            sortYear = users.school,
                            users.name,
                            users.email,
                            users.summoner,
                            users.birthday,
                        };
```